# iOS 7 - Storyboards. Why is it impossible to set tableViewCell selection color

Tags: ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview, xcode-storyboard

In general Storyboards are an awesome hugely productive tool that I cannot live without. But ...
I am pulling my hair out trying to do something I assumed would be trivially simple: set the selection color for a tableView cell. Impossible.

My storyboard is simple: navigationController --root controller--> tableViewController

Here are screenshots.

The app. Notice the pale, sickly grey cell selection color that should be blue.
[image]

Storyboard screenshots.

NavigationController. Notice I set the nav bar to opaque.

[image]

TableViewController. Again, solid opaque nav bar.
[image]

TableViewCell. Notice I set selection color to **blue** not pale, sickly grey.
[image]

Can someone please explain to me how to convince Storyboard how to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your storyboard, do the following:

1. Place a UIView as a background view of your prototype cell. This should be below your UILabels. Change its background color to your desired color. (Background NOT Tint)
2. Select your prototype cell and go to its connections inspector (Command + Alt + 6).
3. Drag the `selectedBackgroundView` outlet into your just placed background view.

Source: [How to change background selected color storyboard static cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850501/how-to-change-background-selected-color-storyboard-static-cells#answer-12522813)

Comment: You sir, are a genius! Now, leveling up, is it possible to set the highlightedTextColor in Storyboard.

Comment: This is nice answer. Was wondering why doing it programatically in the cellfortable delegate is not working.